# restore after "git rm"

Tags: git, restore

I initialized git repo in `some_dir_path` with `git init`. After that, I decided not to include all files into repo and issued `git rm -f`. As I thought, it would remove all files from git repo, not from the directory itself. And now, this `some_dir_path` is empty, except of .git itself:

```
ls -aR some_dir_path:
.git:
branches  config  description  HEAD  hooks  index  info  objects  refs
...
```

So, the question is if there any way to get data back?

I had no commits issued and no branches before `git rm -f` to restore from.

Comment: If you really did only that, why can't you simply remove your directory, recreate it with `mkdir` and re-issue the `git init` command?

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch
  Actually, I want to get data, removed by git, back.

Comment: You'll need backups. Next time, avoid `git rm` on files you did not commit

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch  Thank you for your suggestion! )) I will mind it next time.

Answer (score 2):

Since none of the files had been committed, they are now lost.

Had they been committed, you would have recovered by issuing

```
git reset --hard
```

That would have restored the files removed (and reverted any changes made to other files) since the last commit.

See also `git reset --help`.

Comment: Thank you for a good suggestion about `git reset --hard`, but I tried that as well, and it is also failed to restore.

Comment: @acd Yes. As I wrote, that would require that the files had been checked in.

Comment: Could you, please, detail it: "that would require that the files had been checked in"? By what means, in which way?

Comment: @acd For `git reset --hard` to restore files removed by `git rm ...`, those files would have had to have been checked in with `git commit` before they were removed. Since they weren't, `git reset --hard` will not restore them. That is the essence (but more verbosely) of what I wrote in the answer.

Comment: O.K. I see, it is a poor state. But, anyway, thank you very much for your kind intentions to help!

Answer (score 0):

The `git rm` has not been committed, so the procedure is quite simple:

Starting point: There is a "onefile" added:

```
$  git cat-file -p HEAD:onefile         
content...
$  cat onefile
content...
```

Now the `git rm`:

```
$  git rm -f onefile 
rm 'onefile'
$  ls
```

The file is really gone. The git command is not committed. (The line `rm 'onefile'` is *output*, not a command!)

Advice is easy here and now: don't panic, get an overview:

```
$  git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    onefile
```

So by following the hint:

```
$  git reset HEAD *
Unstaged changes after reset:
D       onefile
```

The delete has gone from uncommitted to unstaged.

```
$  git archive HEAD -o playback.tar
$  tar xf playback.tar --to-stdout
content...
```

If the `git rm` gets committed, a `git reset HEAD~` is needed.

If the repo is empty after just `git init`, the `git rm` command is "safe":

```
$  git rm * 
fatal: pathspec '*' did not match any files
```

The Q hides what went on between init and rm. Must have been git add?